# How can I detect an overflow in binary multiplication?

Tags: binary, overflow, multiplication, flags

I am a little desperate on how to detect an overflow when multiplying two 8-bit signed binary numbers? The result should also have 8-bit.

I multiply them in a microprogram using shift and add instructions. My algorithm works like this in pseudocode for multiplying binary numbers a * b, in addition I have an accumulator:

```
if least significant bit of b = 1 {
    shift a to the left 
    add a to the accumulator
    shift b to the right 
    jump to the if statement
} else {
    shift b to the right 
    jump to the if statement
}
```

When shifting I fill with zeros and I stop this loop when b is zero. When I shift left I shift the most significant bit to the carry bit.

I already multiplied several binary numbers to see if I can find a pattern when the overflow should be set and when it should'nt, but I could not figure out when it should happen.

I also tried to find how the IMUL Assembler instruction sets its flags but I could not find anything that helped.

If anyone has any clue on how this works I would appreciate your help so much! Thanks in advance!

Comment: (Welcome to *posting* on SO (at long last)!) ([`microprogram`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microprogramming) may mean something entirely different.) Without disclosing the machine/assembler targeted, there's only so much anyone can contribute. Integer multiplication instructions yield a double length result in about as many architectures as not - no overflow if they do (but non-zero high part), consult "flag" documentation if yours doesn't. If you don't have access to flags after an unsigned addition: carry if result smaller than either summand, signed: sign (most significant bit) changed.